# Pure algebraic solution to a bounded area calculus problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given a region $\sigma$ in the Cartesian plane is bounded by the lines

$$x = 1,\>\>\> x = 3, \>\>\>y = m,\>\>\> y = mx + 2$$

With $m > 0$. What does $m$ need to be for the region $\sigma$ to have an area of $9$.

The calculus solution is $a = 1, b = 3$ where

$$\int_a^b dx~(mx - m + 2) = 2m + 4$$

Solving for $m$ yields, $\frac{5}{2}$.

I am interested in how to solve this algebraically, considering that these are lines not curves (yes, I know a line is an instance of a curve but I do not know how else to describe my problem) is it possible?

Comment: Hint:  the region in question is a trapezoid, so you can work out its area via geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is a trapezoid with the two base lengths given by

$$y(1)-m = 2, \>\>\> y(3)-m = 2m+2$$

and the height of the trapezoid is $3-1=2$. Thus, its area

$$\frac 12 \times (2+2m+2)\times 2 = 9$$

which has the solution

$$m=\frac 52$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand. How did you know the region is a trapezoid was it from the equations or did you graph it? I graphed it using desmos and had no clue it was a trapezoid. Silly me, has only ever known about right trapezoids.

Comment: because it is enclosed by a horizontal line $y=m$ and a line with an angle $y=mx+2$.

Answer (score 0):

At first i would compute where the intersection point of $$y=mx+2$$ and $$y=m$$ is located:
$$y=mx+2=m$$ so we get $$x=\frac{m-2}{m}$$ and since $m>0$ we get
$$x=\frac{m-2}{m}<1$$ and this is equivalent to $$-2<0$$